How to get the day of a selected date?
I want to display the day next to the current date for a selected month while looping on all days of the month.
var
  dtSelectedDate, dtStartDate, dtEndDate, dtCurrentDate, d1: TDateTime;
begin
  dtSelectedDate := DateOf(CalendarView1.Date);
  dtStartDate := StartOfTheMonth(dtSelectedDate);
  dtEndDate := EndOfTheMonth(dtSelectedDate);

  EditMonth.Text := IntToStr(DaysInMonth(dtSelectedDate));
  EditStartDay.Text := DateToStr(dtStartDate);
  EditEndDay.Text := DateToStr(dtEndDate);

  dtCurrentDate := dtStartDate;
  while dtCurrentDate <= dtEndDate do
  begin
    T1.insert;
    T1.FieldByName('Days').AsDateTime   := dtCurrentDate;
    T1.Post;
    dtCurrentDate := dtCurrentDate + 1;
  end;
end;

I tried DayofWeek(CalendarView1.Date) but it doesn't work, it always returns "Saturday", the first day of October, on all days of October.

The first day of October this year is Tuesday not Saturday.

Inside the loop, use dtCurrentDate
instead of CalendarView1.Date when calling DayOfWeek().
Keep in mind that SysUtils.DayOfWeek() returns integer values 1..7 representing Sunday..Saturday, whereas DateUtils.DayOfTheWeek() returns integer values 1..7 representating Monday..Sunday instead.
If you want the actual name of the day as a string, you can use FormatDateTime() with the ddd or dddd specifier.  Or simply use the DayOfWeek() value to index into the FormatSettings.ShortDayNames or FormatSettings.LongDayNames array.

I added a "Days" field and did like this :  T1.FieldByName('jours').AsString   := FormatSettings.LongDayNames[DayOfWeek(dtCurrentDate)]; it works perfectly

I was looking for this function which interprets the name of the day from the variable (dtCurrentDate).   thanks again

@fatehdjelti there is no  specific function for that exact purpose, but FormatDateTime() would be the closest, eg: FormatDateTime('dddd', dtCurrentDate); which will return the same name as FormatSettings.LongDayNames[DayOfWeek(dtCurrentDate)].
